# Invisible data column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

Why can't I specify `invisible` when creating a table with the above syntax?

Do I need any special privilege?

[[--just for learning purpose--]]

Comment: Invisible column is Oracle 12c's new feature. It seems that you're using Oracle 11g.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/invisible-columns-odb12c-2331522.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need any special privilege?

No, all you need is Oracle 12c version. You are running 11g and invisible columns are a new feature of 12c version of RDBMS:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER                                                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production     
....


SQL> create table t1(
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 number invisible
  4  )
  5  ;

Table created
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that before! :)